# SQL Server 2016 secondary often issued error 3456, how to prevent SQL database error 3456?

Tags: sql-server, alwayson, redo-logs

> Could not redo log record (410417:192254:28), for transaction ID (0:1838907632), on page (1:761914), allocation unit 72057594280869888, database '****' (database ID 5). Page: LSN = (410417:191949:3), allocation unit = 72057594280869888, type = 10. Log: OpCode = 7, context 10, PrevPageLSN: (410417:192254:26). Restore from a backup of the database, or repair the database.

Version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   
Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) 
on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393) (Hypervisor)
```

The error 3456 often occurs in the `INSERT` operation after the `TRUNCATE` table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fn_dump_dblog ('410417:191949:3', '410417:192254:28', N'DISK', 1, N'E:\BackUp\dbname_2019_05_04_020310_6766368.trn',
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
 WHERE \[transaction ID\] ='0000:6d9b80f0'
```

[image]